# Add a callback into a javascript function (application on angularjs)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, callback

i'm looking for a proper way to manage a function callback.
Consider this part of code which is a piece of a angularjs controller:

```
 function($scope, $routeParams, $location, sessionService) {
        sessionService.logout(function(){
            $location.path('/');
        });
    }
```

SessionService is a factory to manage session with login, logout ....
the logout function looks like to:

```
session.logout= function(o){
            console.log('logout')
            $cookieStore.remove('eeToken');
            o();
        };
```

The main of this code is to delete the session token and redirect to the home. The disturbing part is the `o();`. Is there a proper way to do this callback ?

thanks.

Comment: That's the proper way. What's the problem with that?

Comment: there is no problem, it's only an interrogation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem here is really the naming...

```
session.logout= function(loggedOutCallback){
        console.log('logout')
        $cookieStore.remove('eeToken');
        loggedOutCallback();
};
```

Otherwise, this is a valid way to provide a function to be called.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i've my response :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with your code (except the callback name as pointed out by Steve).
Another solution is to use a promise:

```
session.logout = function() {
    console.log('logout')
    $cookieStore.remove('eeToken');

    // Returns a Promise.
    // Don't forget to inject $q!
    return $q.when(true);
};
```

Then:

```
sessionService.logout().then(function() {
  $location.path('/');
));
```